# Looking for a word to describe someone who feels or believes he or she is too good for any improvement

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Another way to frame this is a person who sees him or herself as "good" and is not open to feedback, suggestion or any kind of improvement in their lives because they would interpret these as meaning that they are not good and therefore need improvement. Hence, they keep on protecting their image or belief that they are "good" while rejecting all suggestions or feedback from others.

Basically, the person is overly happy with who he or she is that he or she sees no reasons to improve.

Thank you in advance! I would very much appreciate any suggestion!

---

**PLEASE DO NOT GET INTO A PHILOSOPHICAL DISCUSSION. I JUST WANT SUGGESTION OF POSSIBLE WORDS + EXPLANATION. THANK YOU.**

Comment: I'm having difficulty deciding to focus on the 'hubris'/pride side or more on the self-centred aspect?

Comment: I would be open to both ways of defining it. And it is also possible that in some cases it is a mix of both--the person is proud of himself and is defensive about that pride more than his opportunity to grow which makes that person self-centric.

Comment: Not a word but "stuck in the mud" or "head in the sand"

Answer (score 1):

Although both pride and a self-centred attitude can be in play here a good fit may be:

[***Hubris.***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hubris)

Excessive pride or self-confidence.
*‘the self-assured hubris among economists was shaken in the late 1980s’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hubris

Answer (score 1):

The first adjective that came to mind was: **self-righteous**.

It is used to describe those who believe their opinions are always correct and their actions are for the best because they are convinced of their own moral superiority.